# Licensing light novel or manga cost

Tags: manga-production, light-novel-production, licensing, snow-white-with-the-red-hair, ascendance-of-a-bookworm

I would like to know how much does it costs to license such light novel or manga like ascendence of a bookworm or akagami no shirayukihime?
And is it possible to have two publisher one in English and second in other language in the same region? I would love to publish the books in my native language.

Can I get the estimate procedure and costs (in US Dollar also fine). Does anyone knows it?